# Spark: daily read from Cassandra and save to parquets, how to read only new rows?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to build an ETL process with Spark. My goal is to read from 
Cassandra table and save into parquet files.

What I managed to do so far is reading an entire table from Cassandra, using a Cassandra connector (in pyspark):

```
df = app.sqlSparkContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
        .option("table", my_table)\
        .option("keyspace",my_keyspace)\
        .load()
```

The issue is that my data is growing rapidly, and I would like to repeat the ETL process everyday where I read the newly added rows from Cassandra and save them into a new parquet file.

Having there is no ordering in my Cassandra table, I will not be able to read based on time, is there any way to do it from Spark side instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effective filtering based on time is really possible only if you have time-based first clustering column, something like this:

```
create table test.test (
  pk1 <type>,
  pk2 <type>,
  cl1 timestamp,
  cl2 ...,
  primary key ((pk1, pk2), cl1, cl2));
```

In this case, condition on `cl1`, like this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
val data = { spark.read.cassandraFormat("test", "test").load()}
val filtered = data.filter("cl1 >= cast('2019-03-10T14:41:34.373+0000' as timestamp)")
```

will be effectively pushed into Cassandra, and filtering will happen server side, retrieving only necessary data - this is easy to check with explain - it should generate something like this (pushed filter denoted as `*`):

```
// *Filter ((cl1#23 >= 1552228894373000))
// +- *Scan org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation [pk1#21,pk2#22L,cl1#23,...] 
PushedFilters: [*GreaterThanOrEqual(cl1,2019-03-10 14:41:34.373)], 
ReadSchema: struct<pk1:int,pk2:int,cl1:timestamp,...
```

In all other cases, filtering will happen on Spark side, retrieving all data from Cassandra.